# Resizing rotated rectangle on HTML canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

I have an instance of HTML 5 canvas and a rectangle drawn on it.

My drawing function takes a resizing angle into account and uses relative coordinates.

Relative coordinates're based upon three variables: top left rectangle point, rectangle width and rectangle height.

Rectangle width and rectangle height're calculated using two points: top left rectangle point and bottom right rectangle point.

To sum up, drawing function depends on top left rectangle point, bottom right rectangle point and rotation. It's an important point for the following text!

Here's a code snippet:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('imageCanvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var xTopLeft = 550; 
var yTopLeft = 200;
var xBottomRight = 750; 
var yBottomRight = 450; 
var w = Math.max(xTopLeft, xBottomRight) - Math.min(xTopLeft, xBottomRight);
var h = Math.max(yTopLeft, yBottomRight) - Math.min(yTopLeft, yBottomRight);
var r = 1;

function draw() {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    ctx.save()
    ctx.translate(xTopLeft + w / 2, yTopLeft + h / 2);
    ctx.rotate(r);
    ctx.fillStyle = "yellow";
    ctx.fillRect(w / 2 * (-1), h / 2 * (-1), w, h);
    ctx.restore()
    }
```

Here's my rectangle with a bunch of controls: eight resizing handles (white) and one rotation handle (green):

[image]

Rotating works fine.

Resizing works fine.

And I also try to implement resizing after rotation. Here's my approach with a humble illustration:

[image]

1. Grab the coordinates of the red point (it's mouse cursor coordiantes)
2. Derotate the point using negative angle to get derotated coordinates

```
function rotatePoint(x, y, center_x, center_y, angle) {
    var new_x = (x - cx) * Math.cos(angle) - (y - cy) * Math.sin(angle) + cx;
    var new_y = (x - cx) * Math.sin(angle) + (y - cy) * Math.cos(angle) + cy;
    return [new_x, new_y]
}
```

3. Update `xTopLeft`, `yTopLeft` and redraw
4. Done

The idea behind this approach is simple. Since my drawing function depeneds on top left rectangle point and bottom right rectangle point I just need to get their new coordinates.

For instance, here's a simplified code for B point:

```
if (point == 'B') {
    var newPointB = rotatePoint(mouse.x, mouse.y, center_x, center_y, -r);
    xBottomRight = newPointB[0];
    yTopLeft = newPointB[1];
}
```

But it doesn't work as expected: while resizing my rotated rectangle shifts, jumps and totally misbehaves.

In search of insights I've stumbled upon [this article](https://shihn.ca/posts/2020/resizing-rotated-elements/). The article covers my problem, but I don't get author's approach and can't implement it.

Why should I always lock the coordinates of the A point? My top left handle is intended to resize the rectangle in a north-west direction, so it would be necessary to change the coordinates of the A point...

Why should we recalculate the center point before derotation? It breaks the idea of uniform matrix transformations...

What's the correct algorithm in my case?

Comment: When you "derotate" the mouse point, you're using `-angle` of the current rotation of the rectangle, correct?  Also, in the referenced article the `A` point is simply the point opposite the drag point.  In your example, you will lock the `C` point during the drag operation...

Comment: @Trentium yes, for de-rotation I use negative angle: `newPoint = rotatePoint(mouse.x, mouse.y, center_x, center_y, -angle)`. I tried locking opposite points, but rectangle keeps shifting....

Comment: Note also that when resizing, the center x & y are changing by half the distance of the drag change (ie, your rectangle is growing or shrinking, so the center point of the rectangle is changing), and in doing so, if locking the opposite corner of the drag, this will require a change in position of the rectangle to keep the locked corner in place relative to the global coordinates.

Answer (score 1):

I was also facing same problem. It turned out that the angle I was using was in degree. Try multiplying angle in rotatePoint function with (Math.PI / 180).

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thank you! I had this issue myself.